# Как сделать чтобы настройки соответствовали

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Есть количество символов в колонке. В зависимости от ширины экрана количество символов разное, например 9 символов в колонке, а где-то все правильно и их количество как указано. Как сделать, чтобы количество символов совпадало с настройками, и их было одинаковое количество везде?

```js
var canv = document.getElementById("canv"),
ctx = canv.getContext("2d"),
w = canv.width = window.innerWidth,
h = canv.height = window.innerHeight
var opts = {
    colAmount: 10,
    lettersInCol: 8,
    spacing: 20,
    letters: [0, 1]
}
var colSize = (w - opts.spacing * opts.colAmount) / opts.colAmount;
var fSize = colSize / opts.lettersInCol;
ctx.font = fSize + "px sans-serif";

for(let i = 0; i < opts.colAmount; i++) {
    let target = (colSize + opts.spacing) * i + opts.spacing/2;
    ctx.save()
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
    ctx.fillRect(target, 0, colSize, h) // вспомогательные прямоугольники
    ctx.restore()
    for(let x = target; x < target+colSize; x += fSize) {
        for(let y = fSize; y < h + fSize; y += fSize) {
            ctx.fillText(opts.letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * opts.letters.length)], x, y)
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0;">
 <canvas id="canv" style="position: absolute;"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не учитываете погрешности при делении. А также пытаетесь задать ширину шрифта, а не размер. Такое может "прокатить" с моноширинными шрифтами (аля *Courier*, *Consolas* и т.п.), но с пропорциональными - "грабли и костыли"...

Самый простой способ, если количество колонок неизменно - подставить нужный коэффициент, нивелирующий погрешности вычислений.

```js
var canv = document.getElementById("canv"),
  ctx = canv.getContext("2d"),
  w = canv.width = window.innerWidth,
  h = canv.height = window.innerHeight;
var opts = {
  colAmount: 10,
  lettersInCol: 8,
  spacing: 20,
  letters: [0, 1]
};
var colSize = (w - opts.spacing * opts.colAmount) / opts.colAmount;
var fSize = colSize / opts.lettersInCol / .98; // Коэффициент
ctx.font = fSize + "px san-serif";

for (let i = 0; i < opts.colAmount; i++) {
  let target = (colSize + opts.spacing) * i + opts.spacing / 2;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  ctx.fillRect(target, 0, colSize, h); // вспомогательные прямоугольники
  ctx.restore();
  for (let x = target; x < target + colSize; x += fSize) {
    for (let y = fSize; y < h + fSize; y += fSize) {
      ctx.fillText(opts.letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * opts.letters.length)], x, y)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0;">
  <canvas id="canv" style="position: absolute;"></canvas>
</body>
```

[Источник 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)
[Источник 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495872/how-is-font-size-calculated)

Comment: Немного не понятно, когда вы говорили про то, что я пытался задать ширину, а не размер. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font Написано, задается размер.https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText Чтобы задать ширину нужно использовать filltext. Разве нет? Также не понятно про погрешности. Как они могут быть если на моем мониторе получается ровно 14.575 в значении fSize? Как вычислялся коэффициент?

Comment: @Василий , задавая значение шрифту, Вы меняете `font-size`, он же [кегль](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8C) шрифта. По сути, кегль - это **высота** знакоместа со всеми присущими шрифтам [атрибутами](http://setmefirst.ru/var/setmefirst_ru/storage/images/blog/verstka_internet_statej_sdelaj_bukvy_chitabel_nymi/1348-1-eng-US/verstka_internet_statej_sdelaj_bukvy_chitabel_nymi_21_dekabrya_2015_g.gif). Ширина для шрифта понятие относительное, если не сказать абстрактное. Вы пытаетесь подогнать ширину, управляя высотой. Коэффициент как раз и задаёт нужные пропорции ширине.